# mysql password unrecognized after exit terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords

i'm new in sql.

I have mamp.

I program in terminal and i don't understand why my password for connect to mysql doesn't work after a first connection.

If I'm connect for first time after launch mamp, it work. But after it says password incorrect ...

I don't understand why because I can connect if I restart mamp with the same password.

Anyone have answer ?

thx for time.